# How do I set the ContentType in a ServiceStack client?

Tags: c#, forms, ormlite-servicestack

I am using a ServiceStack client to call a webservice as follows:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(apiUrl);
var url = "/V1/MyApiCall";

var response = client.Post<MyApiCallResponse>(url, "foo=" + request.foo + "&bar=" + request.bar);
```

This generally works well, however I need to change the Content-Type header.  By default (and for most other calls I am making from the service) this needs to be `application/json`, but in this particular case it needs to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

`client.ContentType` does not implement a setter, so how can I change the Content-Type header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use [Servicestack's C# Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) to call 3rd party API's. You're using a JSON client which as expected sends JSON. You can use [ServiceStack's built-in HTTP Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils) if you need to call 3rd Party APIs, look at the [POSTing data examples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils#posting-data), e.g:

```
var response = url.PostToUrl(new { foo = request.foo, bar = request.bar },
                   acceptContentType = "application/json")
    .FromJson<MyApiCallResponse>();
```

Comment: Thanks mythz, that makes sense.  BTW, the url parameter has been duplicated (not needed within the parameter list), but since the edit is under 6 chars, SO won't let me fix it.